# SQL Query for getting total students who registered for more then 5 courses in a semester

Tags: sql

I am new with sql queries so dont know much

i have a table named registration

this table has the following structure

```
Student_ID int,
Course varchar(15),
Score int,
Semester varchar(15),
Discipline varchar(10),
Campus varchar(15),
Degree varchar(10),
Year int
```

it does not contain any primary key it has the data of students from 4 different campuses of the same university so student_id is repeated

i am required total number of students who have taken more then 5 courses in a  particular semester

i hope i have made the question clear kindly help if any one can.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT` to get all the students that have taken more than five courses:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE Semester = ....
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Course) > 5
```

To get the number of students you can count the number of rows that query returns:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM
(
    SELECT student_id
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE Semester = ....
    GROUP BY student_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Course) > 5
)
```

Comment: Thank You very much Mark this worked helped alot once again thank you very much my man

Answer (score 0):

To get the students who are registered for more than 5 courses you do this...

```
SELECT CAMPUS, STUDENT_ID
FROM REGISTRATION
WHERE SEMESTER = 'GIVEN SEMESTER'
GROUP BY CAMPUS, STUDENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

To get the number of students who are registered for more than 5 courses you do this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM REGISTRATION
WHERE SEMESTER = 'GIVEN SEMESTER'
GROUP BY CAMPUS, STUDENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

You need to group by campus AND student id since student id is repeated for different campuses. Also, the primary key should be composite (campus, student_id, semester, year, course) if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes Waleed You did get my question right,i got the query its working thank you very much really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(sub.Student_ID)) FROM
(
SELECT un.Student_ID, COUNT(*) FROM university un 
GROUP BY un.Student_ID, un.Semester
HAVING 
COUNT(un.Course)>5
) AS sub
```

I assume the table name is university